retaining dropdown values in web form after form submit?
I have a form where I'd like two dropdown values to retain their values if a form is submitted.
 // Function to save submitted values to local storage
  function saveSubmittedValues() {
    var supervisor = document.getElementById("supervisor").value;
    var substation = document.getElementById("substation").value;
    
    // Save submitted values to local storage
    localStorage.setItem("supervisor", supervisor);
    localStorage.setItem("substation", substation);
  }
 // Function to pre-fill dropdowns with saved values from local storage
  function prefillDropdowns() {
    // Retrieve saved values from local storage
    var supervisor = localStorage.getItem("supervisor");
    var substation = localStorage.getItem("substation");

    // Pre-fill supervisor dropdown
    if (supervisor) {
      document.getElementById("supervisor").value = supervisor;
    }

    // Pre-fill substation dropdown
    if (substation) {
      document.getElementById("substation").value = substation;
      // Trigger the onchange event of substation dropdown to populate parcels
      getParcels(substation);
    }
  }

// Call the setDefaultDate function when the page is loaded
window.onload = setDefaultDate;

function validateForm() {
  var isValid = true;
  var supervisor = document.getElementById("supervisor").value;
  var substation = document.getElementById("substation").value;
  var parcel = document.getElementById("parcel").value;
  var parcelId = document.getElementById("parcelId").value;
  var status = document.getElementById("status").value;
  var date = document.getElementById("datePicker").value;
  var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;

  // Check if any field is null or blank
  if (!supervisor || !substation || !parcel || !parcelId || !status || !date || !comment) {
    document.getElementById("submit-message").innerText = "All fields must be filled.";
    return false; // Prevent form submission
  }

  // Save submitted values to local storage
  saveSubmittedValues();

  // Call prefillDropdowns function to update dropdowns with new values
  prefillDropdowns();

  // Disable form submit button to prevent resubmission
  document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = true;

  return true; // Allow form submission
}

it keeps resetting the values instead of retaining them in local storage to populate back in dropdown preview window when form is submitted. Any ideas how I can achieve this?
Rest of html code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <title>Daily Contact Form </title>
  <style>
    /* Your CSS styles here */
    body {
      font-size: 15px;
      background-color: #f0f8ff;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif; /* Light blue background color */
    }
    .container {
      width: 50%;
      margin: 0 auto; /* Center the container horizontally */
      text-align: center; /* Center the content inside the container */
      padding-top: 20px; /* Add space at the top */
    }
    h1 {
      margin-top: 20px; /* Add space between header image and header text */
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    select {
      width: 50%; /* Set the width of dropdown menus to fill the container */
      font-size: 12px; /* Set font size for dropdown values */
      text-align-last: center; /* Align dropdown selections in the middle */
    }
    /* Additional styling to center-align dropdown selections */
    option {
      text-align: center;
    }
    textarea {
      height: 100px;
      width: 250px;
      font-size: 12px;
      width: 100%; /* Set font size for textarea */
    }
    input[type="submit"] {
      font-size: 12px; /* Set font size for submit button */
    }
    .submit-message {
      color: red;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    .landowner-info {
      float: center;
      margin-top: 20px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      width: 100%; /* Extend size of landowner info box */
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
  <script>

// Function to set the default date to today's date
function setDefaultDate() {
  var today = new Date();
  var day = today.getDate();
  var month = today.getMonth() + 1; // Months are zero indexed
  var year = today.getFullYear();

  // Format the date as YYYY-MM-DD for the input field
  var formattedDate = year + '-' + (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' + (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day;

  // Set the default value of the date picker input field directly
  var datePicker = document.getElementById("datePicker");
  datePicker.setAttribute("value", formattedDate);

  // Set the value of the text box to the same date
  datePicker.value = formattedDate;
}


function updateMaxStatusAndLandownerInfo(parcelId) {
  updateMaxStatusForParcel(parcelId); // Call updateMaxStatusForParcel with the selected Parcel ID
  getLandownerInfo(parcelId); // Call getLandownerInfo with the selected Parcel ID
}

    function updateParcelInfo(landowner) {
      // Trigger search in "Raw Data" worksheet for landowner value
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(parcelIds) {
        var parcelIdDropdown = document.getElementById("parcelId");
        parcelIdDropdown.innerHTML = "";
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = "";
        option.text = "";
        parcelIdDropdown.appendChild(option);

        // Populate Parcel ID dropdown with matching rows from columns U3:U
        parcelIds.forEach(function(parcelId) {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = parcelId;
          option.text = parcelId;
          parcelIdDropdown.appendChild(option);
        });
      }).getParcelIdsByLandowner(landowner); // Call server function to get matching parcel IDs
    }

function getLandownerInfo(parcel) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(landownerInfo) {
    document.getElementById("landowner-info-content").innerText = landownerInfo;
  }).getLandownerInfo(parcel);
}

    function getParcels(substation) {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(parcels) {
        var parcelDropdown = document.getElementById("parcel");
        parcelDropdown.innerHTML = "";
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = "";
        option.text = "";
        parcelDropdown.appendChild(option);

        // Sort the parcel options alphabetically
        parcels.sort().forEach(function(parcel) {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = parcel;
          option.text = parcel;
          parcelDropdown.appendChild(option);
        });

        // Update max status immediately after selecting parcel
        var selectedParcel = parcelDropdown.value;
        updateParcelInfo(selectedParcel);
      }).getParcels(substation);
    }

// Inside the updateMaxStatusForParcel function, where the status dropdown is being populated
function updateMaxStatusForParcel(parcel) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(maxStatus) {
    var statusDropdown = document.getElementById("status");
    statusDropdown.innerHTML = ""; // Clear previous options

    // Define status options in the desired order
    var statusOptions = ["", "Assigned to Agent", "Outreach", "Negotiating", "Pledged", "Signed", "Dropped"];

    // Add options to the dropdown in the defined order
    statusOptions.forEach(function(status) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = status;
      option.text = status;
      if (status === maxStatus) {
        option.selected = true; // Select the option if it matches the max status
      }
      statusDropdown.appendChild(option);
    });
  }).getMaxStatusForParcel(parcel);
}

  // Function to save submitted values to local storage
  function saveSubmittedValues() {
    var supervisor = document.getElementById("supervisor").value;
    var substation = document.getElementById("substation").value;
    
    // Save submitted values to local storage
    localStorage.setItem("supervisor", supervisor);
    localStorage.setItem("substation", substation);
  }
 // Function to pre-fill dropdowns with saved values from local storage
  function prefillDropdowns() {
    // Retrieve saved values from local storage
    var supervisor = localStorage.getItem("supervisor");
    var substation = localStorage.getItem("substation");

    // Pre-fill supervisor dropdown
    if (supervisor) {
      document.getElementById("supervisor").value = supervisor;
    }

    // Pre-fill substation dropdown
    if (substation) {
      document.getElementById("substation").value = substation;
      // Trigger the onchange event of substation dropdown to populate parcels
      getParcels(substation);
    }
  }

// Call the setDefaultDate function when the page is loaded
window.onload = setDefaultDate;

function validateForm() {
  var isValid = true;
  var supervisor = document.getElementById("supervisor").value;
  var substation = document.getElementById("substation").value;
  var parcel = document.getElementById("parcel").value;
  var parcelId = document.getElementById("parcelId").value;
  var status = document.getElementById("status").value;
  var date = document.getElementById("datePicker").value;
  var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;

  // Check if any field is null or blank
  if (!supervisor || !substation || !parcel || !parcelId || !status || !date || !comment) {
    document.getElementById("submit-message").innerText = "All fields must be filled.";
    return false; // Prevent form submission
  }

  // Save submitted values to local storage
  saveSubmittedValues();

  // Call prefillDropdowns function to update dropdowns with new values
  prefillDropdowns();

  // Disable form submit button to prevent resubmission
  document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = true;

  return true; // Allow form submission
}


    // Prevent form resubmission popup on page reload
    if (window.history.replaceState) {
      window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function () {
        window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.href);
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/16QsZja.png" alt="Header Image" style="width: 100%; max-width: 200px;">

    <h1>Daily Contact Form</h1>

    <form method="post" action="<?= getUrl() ?>" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
      <label>Land Agent</label><br>
      <select name="supervisor" id="supervisor">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Dan">Dan</option>
        <option value="Ian">Ian</option>
        <option value="Parker">Parker</option>
      </select><br><br>

      <label>Substation</label><br>
      <select name="substation" id="substation" onchange="getParcels(this.value)">
        <option value=""></option>
        <? var subs = getDistinctSubstations(); ?>
        <? subs.sort().forEach(function(sub) { ?>
          <option value="<?= sub ?>"><?= sub ?></option>
        <? }); ?>
      </select><br><br>

      <label>Landowner</label><br>
      <select name="landowner" id="parcel" onchange="updateParcelInfo(this.value)">
        <!-- Parcel dropdown will be populated dynamically -->
      </select><br><br>

      <label>Parcel ID</label><br>
      <select name="parcelId" id="parcelId" onchange="updateMaxStatusAndLandownerInfo(this.value)">
        <!-- Parcel ID dropdown will be populated dynamically -->
      </select><br><br>

      <label>Status</label><br>
      <select name="status" id="status">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Assigned to Agent">Passed to Agent</option>
        <option value="Outreach">Outreach</option>
        <option value="Negotiating">Negotiating</option>
        <option value="Pledged">Pledged</option>
        <option value="Signed">Signed</option>
        <option value="Denied">Denied</option>
      </select><br><br>

<label for="date">Date</label><br>
<input type="date" name="date" id="datePicker"><br><br>

      <label>Comment</label><br>
      <textarea name="comment" id="comment"></textarea><br><br>

      <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submit-button" value="Submit" />
      <span id="submit-message" class="submit-message"></span>
    </form>
<div class="landowner-info">
  <h2>Landowner Info</h2>
  <p id="landowner-info-content"></p> <!-- Display landowner information -->
</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>


You're calling prefillDropdowns before you submit the form, not after the page reloads.

When the page reloads you call setDefaultDate. That needs to call prefillDropdowns to load them from localStorage.

Remove prefillDropdowns(); from validateForm, because you are submitting the form, but you did not reload yet at this point. Then, change your command of window.onload = setDefaultDate;
to
window.onload = function() {
    setDefaultDate();
    prefillDropdowns();
};

Make sure that no errors occur during your tests and then it should work.
